# How to group by table with null values together

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by

I have table with rows:

```
Id, Name, Age, Field1, Field2
-----------------------------
1, 'Person_1', 23, NULL, 5
2, 'Person_1', 23, 3, NULL
3, 'Person_2, 25, 7, NULL
```

I want to group it to have result like this:

```
'Person_1', 23, 3, 5
'Person_2, 25, 7, NULL
```

I tried to do subquery and select Field1 and Field2 but it always gets first row of single person for field1 and field2

Comment: Which one  – Postgres or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Age), MAX(Field1), MAX(Field2)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Name
```

`MAX` aggregate function will return `NULL` if *all*, e.g. `Field2`, values are `NULL`, otherwise it will ignore `NULL`s and return the maximum value of the field.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2848d/2)